# windows 2003 doesn't open cmd as "interact with desktop" when using scheduled tasks

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

i have two windows servers : windows server 2003 and windows server 2008.

in windows 2008 when i start a batch script through scheduled task,
it opens a visible CMD window with my batch on it.
in windows 2003 on the other hand when i start a batch script through scheduled task,
it doesn't open a visible CMD window (interact with desktop not available?) but i can see the process of the batch running in the background.

does anyone knows how can i activate the Desktop? so i can see the CMD open

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so i found the solution. there were two thing i had to do:

A- check the checkbox for "Run only if logged in" in the task itself.

B- enable "Allow service to interact with desktop" on the task scheduler service.

1.)Click Start, click Control Panel, and then double-click Administrative Tools.

2.)Click Computer Management.

3.)Expand Services and Applications, and then click Services.

4.)Right-click the Task Scheduler service, and then click Properties.

5.)On the General tab, make sure that the startup type is set to automatic, and that the service status is Started. If the service is not running, click Start.

6.)On the Log On tab, make sure that the local system account is selected, and that the Allow service to interact with desktop check box has a check mark.

7.)Click OK, and then quit Computer Management.